# Does MongoDB Realm version 10 supports same operators mentioned in MongoDB Realm version 6 or legacy

Tags: react-native, realm

I am looking at new documentation of MongoDB realm but there I'm not able to find much example so wondering operators mentioned in [legacy](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-legacy/docs/javascript/latest/), will work same as in latest version which is version [10](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/introduction)

I want to filter with AND operator but in version 10 not able to find filtered example with AND operator or not able to see list of supported Operators

Answer (score 0):

I find out the list of query operator in [references](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/reference/realm-query-language/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).